# How to view "quick" statistics for a table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, statistics

In ArcMap i can [view statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/viewing-statistics-for-a-table.htm) describing the values in numeric columns of the attribute table by right-clicking the field name and then click Statistics:

[image]

I cant find statistics like this in ArcGIS Pro, instead it will open the geoprocessing tool "Summary Statistics". How can i display quick statistics for a field in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post on GeoNet: [How do I get statistics for a field?](https://community.esri.com/thread/164067) and this ArcGIS Idea: [Summary Statistics Workflow in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/ideas/11923-summary-statistics-workflow-in-arcgis-pro), this functionnality doesn't exist yet in Pro but it is in production plan, it will probably be included in release 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the "Statistics" option instead of "Summarize" it produces a similar result as ArcDesktop.